# Show window that covers everything when apps enters background

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, ios13

In iOS12 and below I used to use something similar to this to show a window on top of everything to cover my app contents. This use to work but in iOS13 betas this does not work anymore.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var coverWindow: UIWindow?

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        if self.coverWindow != nil {
            // Skip since cover window is already showing
            return
        }
        let vc = UIViewController()
        let label = UILabel(frame: window!.bounds)
        label.text = "CoverWindow. Tap to app see contents"
        vc.view = label
        vc.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        let coverWindow = UIWindow(frame: window!.bounds)
        coverWindow.rootViewController = vc
        coverWindow.windowLevel = .alert
        coverWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()
        self.coverWindow = coverWindow
    }

}
```

Apparently window changes are not reflected in screen until app enters foreground again.

### Question

Does anyone know how fix or workaround this? or maybe this approach is incorrect?

Any help would be highly appreciated

### Notes

1. I don't use a simple view because my app might be showing other windows too and my requirement is to cover everything.
2. I don't use `applicationWillResignActive` because we want to only show coverWindow when it enters background. (TouchID authentication and other stuff might trigger `applicationWillResignActive` and coverWindow would incorrectly show)

### Example code

Download [Full working example code in Github](https://github.com/nacho4d/ScreenCover) (Run in iOS simulator 12 and 13 to see the difference)

Comment: I'd advise to use `applicationWillResignActive`, it's much more reliable on doing this, you can show touchID when user goes back to active state

Comment: TouchID authentication alerts actually make application resign active state. No only TouchID but push notification acceptance alerts too and many other services. I would need to use a BOOL flag en each case ... I would like to avoid this approach if possible

Comment: Hi, did you find solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to myself.

I reported this to Apple and it was fixed in iOS 13.1 or so. Latest version of iOS13 does NOT have this bug :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement application life cycle, you just delete it , add those app life cycle functions and implement your codes , it ll be run without error

Comment: Am I missing something? App application life cycle methods are optional. I removed because I thought they were not needed in this example. This runs fine in iOS12 and below (from iOS9 to iOS12). I wonder what method is missing